# Datepicker onSelect

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

I have an input [date_caisse] with class: datepicker-inline AND id: [date_caisse]

I have this function initialized on all my web pages:

```
function InitEvents () {

$('.datepicker-inline').datepicker({

    showButtonPanel: true,  /*added by oussama*/
    changeMonth: true, /*added by oussama*/
    changeYear: true, /*added by oussama*/
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',/*'dd/mm/yy'*/
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        //alert('select!');
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        parts = id.split('-');
        id2 = parts[parts.length -1];
        $('#datepicker-target-id-' + id2).val(dateText);
    }
});
```

}

I want to apply onSelect only on the current page, so this is what I did:

```
$('#date_caisse').datepicker({

    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        alert('select!');
    }
});
```

When I put  *alert('select!');* on the main js file (which is called in all pages) it works! but it doesn't when I try to trigger the action through the current file.

Maybe, onSelect shouldn't be called twice.

So, anyone could help me please?

**Thanks and have a good day!**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you put your second function inside a jquery initialization block?
I mean, it should looks like

```
$(function(){
   $('#date_caisse').datepicker({
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
         alert('select!');
      }
   });
});
```

#### Edited:

Ok, I got it.
The first time the datepicker is initialized, the original dom element is marked with a new class addition, called *hasDatepicker* that prevent subsequent initialization/reconfiguration.
The way I found to get rid of it is to remove that marker befor doing any modification to the datepicker's configuration.
Thus:

```
$(function() {
   $('#date_caisse').removeClass('hasDatepicker');
   $('#date_caisse').datepicker({
       onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
           alert('overridden!');
       }
   });
});
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Hi, **thanks** for the answer. 
I tried what you said but it's not working.

I guess the problem is that my function datepicker() is called twice:
When i delete **function InitEvents ()** from the common script on all my pages, the current scipt works properly and trigger the alert.

What shall I do ...

Comment: @Keyser_Soze: I edited my answer, after a few investigations I found out the problem. I also pubblished the test on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themarcuz/aezN3/) but I think jsFiddle has some problem now that they moved on the cloud: the test works, but it doesn't anymore as long as I save it on my account :/

Comment: The perfect answer!
I try it on my website and it's working. Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: A "more perfect" answer below - found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9806960

Answer (score 4):

Note: the datepicker does *not* fire the change event for the element if you set the `onSelect` option.

If there is any chance you need to respond to the `change` event for the element you need to remember to fire the change event yourself when setting `onSelect()`, e.g.:

```
$(function(){
   $('#date_caisse').datepicker({
      onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
         alert('select!');
         // Remember to fire the change event...
         if (inst.input) {
             inst.input.trigger('change');
         };
      }
   });
});
```

An alternative to using `onSelect` is to bind to the `dateSelected` event which the datepicker fires.