# jQuery - how to alter Datepicker settings after it has been initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I would like to bind to initialized datepicker "onSelect" function.

I've been trying hard to find a solution on the web, but was unsuccessful.

Anyone can tell me how to do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't just reinitialize and bind to the `onselect` event? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect . Or bind to it in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by reinitialize? I've tried firing the datepicker method once again on the same element, but with no luck `$('#OfferStartDate').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            console.debug("Validation");
        }
    });`
By "no luck" I mean that nothing is displayed on the console.

Comment: There is something else wrong with your code then. What you posted works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6pCMR/ . In regards to my previous comment it sounded like you were trying to modify an existing datepicker, not create a new one - `bind to initialized "onSelect" function`

Comment: Probably there is in fact something else wrong with my code. For now I don't know what, but the solution below (the accepted one - in case others show up) works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can simply use the setter

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('#datepicker').datepicker("option", "onSelect", function(){alert('hi')});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nhmsZ/

Comment: Protip - When posting jQuery UI fiddles I include this theme as a resource that makes everything look nice. Its the top hit for `aristo theme demo` - http://jsfiddle.net/6pCMR/

Comment: what u men by .datepicker(); can u explain

Answer (score 1):

I found the above solutions caused problems in my case. Setting onSelect after the datepicker has already been initialised seems to cause the datepicker to be reinitialised. This may not be desirable.

If you are having problems it may be necessary to go through the back-door. This could have compatibility issues when JQUI is updated, but if you are willing to deal with that, then this code could help you out...

```
var inst = $.datepicker._getInst($('#startdate').get(0));
inst.settings.onSelect = function (dt) {
    // your code here
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First off Nicola's answer is correct and helped me.  I was finding a few related posts that were not really solving my problem.

I'm writing this to expand on the existing answer.  If you use a framework that limits your ability to control the order of execution of your JavaScript, say for example Zend Framework, you might need to fire off that bind option with a delay.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function imahackfunction() {
            $('#startdate').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function () {
                alert($('#startdate').val());
            });
        }
        setTimeout(imahackfunction, 2000);
    });
```

The above worked for me as I've got two `$(document).ready(function() {` blocks, one I open in my view, the other "injected" by the framework which instantiates the datepicker.

What I wonder is why the datepicker does not simply fire the `change` event on the input associated by the `altField` property...