# Why are there two different syntaxes for this in jQuery/bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I found these two examples for these two different events:

```
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker().on('changeDate', myFunction );
$(".datepickerSelect").datepicker( 'option' , 'onSelect', myFunction );
```

Also are they interchangeable like so?

```
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker().on('onSelect', myFunction   );
$(".datepickerSelect").datepicker( 'option' , 'changeDate', myFunction );
```

Comment: can you point the source where you found this example

Comment: the onSelect example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806742/jquery-how-to-alter-datepicker-settings-after-it-has-been-initialized the other example is working code from a project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax of attaching an event listener to an element. It is used used at all the places in jquery

```
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker().on('changeDate', myFunction );
```

The advantage is that you  can add multiple handlers:

```
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker().on('changeDate', otherFunction );
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker().on('changeDate', yetAnotherFunction);
```

Another syntax is:

```
  $('.datepickerSelect').datepicker({'changeDate', myFunction });
```

This syntax means you provide handler for changeDate during initialization of datepicker as part of configuration object. You can attach only one handler  this way.

It is equivalent to doing this

```
$('.datepickerSelect').datepicker('option','changeDate', myFunction);
```

This syntax means you forgot to add changeDate handler in config object during initialization of datepicker, so you are adding it now(or you may want to replace the existing handler added during initialisation).