# Fetch the value from input box contain month-date format by javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to fetch the value of the date and want to increase  by 1 year and set the value for the next date .but if i am putting text i am getting alert if i am just choosing from datepicker i am not getting any alert.

```
<style>
.datepicker-days{display:none!important;}
.datepicker-months{display:block!important;}
.prev{visibility:hidden!important;}
.next{visibility:hidden!important;}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.from').datepicker({
   minDate:new Date(),
    maxDate:'5yr',
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
})

$('#gMonth2').on("change", function () {
alert();
  //alert($(this).val());
});
  });

</script>

<div class="container-fluid" id="content">


<div class="form-group">

    <label>First check in:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-1 datepicker input-sm from" id="gMonth2"  placeholder="CheckIn" >
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - how to alter Datepicker settings after it has been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806742/jquery-how-to-alter-datepicker-settings-after-it-has-been-initialized)

Comment: @mickmackusa see I have used your solution in my project but if I choose the random date its not coming correct so code is having some issue so I did not.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your latest failing coding attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your code in [here](https://codepen.io/majidzeno/pen/NLdvxJ), I'm getting alert with the value fetched from the input when I change the date on the date picker, your code seems to be working fine.

```
.
```

Comment: the link is not working .please check . @Majid Eltayeb

Comment: Check it out now... sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onSelect() event of datepicker

```
$('.from').datepicker({
minDate:new Date(),
maxDate:'5yr',
format: 'mm/yyyy',
onSelect: function(dateText) {
   //Increase year by 1 & set to other field
   }
});
```